# What is the environment for cron?

Tags: cron

When issues arise using `cron` to schedule events, a frequently-heard explanation is that `cron` runs with a different set of *environment* variables than a "normal" user (e.g. `pi`). That's all well and good, but what *is* the *environment* for the `cron` user? If one is to avoid errors due to an incorrect *environment* when using `cron`, it would be useful to know what that *environment* is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can ask `cron` to tell us what its *environment* is.

- Create a shell script in your home directory (`~/`) as follows (or with the editor of your choice):

```
$ nano ~/envtst.sh
```

- Enter/C+P the following in the editor:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh 
echo "env report follows for user "$USER >> /home/pi/envtst.sh.out 
env >> /home/pi/envtst.sh.out 
echo "env report for user "$USER" concluded" >> /home/pi/envtst.sh.out
echo " " >> /home/pi/envtst.sh.out
```

- Save the file and exit the editor; then set the file permissions as executable, and open your `crontab` for editing:

```bsh
$ chmod a+rx ~/envtst.sh
$ crontab -e
```

- Enter the following line at the bottom of your `crontab`:

```bsh
* * * * *  /home/pi/envtst.sh >> /home/pi/envtst.sh.err 2>&1
```

- Save and exit your `crontab`. Use `tail` to view the output & (hopefully) observe the *environment* for `cron`. If there's nothing in the file after a minute, view the file `~/envtst.sh.err` for error messages, and adjust as required.  (NOTE: If you want to clear all prior error messages after troubleshooting: `$ > ~/envtst.sh.err` )

```bsh
crontab: installing new crontab
$ tail -f ~/envtst.sh.out
env report follows for user 
HOME=/home/pi
LOGNAME=pi
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin
LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
SHELL=/bin/sh
PWD=/home/pi
env report for user  concluded
```

This will repeat every minute, so enter `^C` to stop the `tail` listing, edit your `crontab` again to "comment out" (or delete) the line just added. Save and exit the editor.

- Note in the `tail` output above that `cron` has a rather sparse *environment*; only six (6) variables are used to define it. Note the `PATH` consists of only two directories. This is why your crontab entry fails if, for example, you're trying to launch a Python script that resides in your home directory. Note also that the user name (aka LOGNAME iaw System V) isn't `cron` - it's `pi`!
- If you're not familiar, with your own user *environment*, it's useful to compare it against the `cron` *environment*. We'll use the same shell script to add that to the "output" file `~/envtst.sh.out`:

```bsh
$ ~/envtst.sh 
$
```

- To view the output, open `~/envtst.sh.out`in your editor, or `cat ~/envtst.sh.out` to see it in your terminal. It will likely be a fairly extensive output; 30 lines of text, more or less. Note in particular the following lines (assuming you've run this as user `pi`) :

```bsh
USER=pi
...
HOME=/home/pi 
LOGNAME=pi
_=/home/pi/envtst.sh
...
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games 
...
SHELL=/bin/bash
```

- You'll notice numerous differences in the two *environments*. This will help create rational `cron` jobs, and help troubleshooting when they don't behave as you'd like.

Comment: Very nice!  For some reason your `$USER` variable isn't set -- see `env report for user  concluded`.

Comment: @MarkSmith: If you're referring to the absence of $USER in the `cron` environment, it's not that it's not set... it's just not used in the version of `cron` on Raspbian (and Debian I think). [Here's some more on that](https://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/152400-unix-user-logname-environment-variables.html), and [still more](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-users/2015-July/281503.html), and [more](https://comm.support.ca.com/kb/user-vs-logname-environment-variables/kb000037575). Likely more to this story, but I don't think $USER defined for `cron` in any Raspbian distro

Comment: @MarkSmith: It just dawned on me the line you referenced: `env report for user  concluded`. Yeah... :) I stuck that in the script to emphasize that $USER isn't defined :P